# How to show updated data in <h:dataTable> on opening of jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jsf

In a JSF page I use a jQuery dialog to open list of certain data. On click event when I open the dialog it shows the proper list of records but when I add new record in background and again clicked to open the dialog it does not show updated list.

How should I show the updated data?

Comment: You should rerender the datatable on some AJAX event (i.e. when you add a new record to it) so that the client will have an updated datatable. To answer your question you should post the whole code so that we-ll be able to derive the bottlenecks.

Comment: are you using an ajax call back ?